# C++ Xlib program gets color of pixel under pointer, but Firefox throws BadValue error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, xlib

I wrote a program in c++ that gets the color of the pixel currently hovered by the pointer on my ubuntu distribution using Xlib. It works with every window but the firefox one. When I try it on firefox it prints an error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  91 (X_QueryColors)
  Value in failed request:  0xffffffff
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

This is the sourcecode that causes this error when the pointer hovers a firefox window:

```
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/X.h>


int main(int, char**) {
    XColor c;
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XSynchronize(display, True);
    Window child, root_win;
    int root_x, root_y, win_x, win_y;
    unsigned int mask_return;
    XQueryPointer(display, root, &root_win, &child, &root_x, &root_y, &win_x, &win_y, &mask_return);
    
    XWindowAttributes child_attr;
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, child, &child_attr);
    std::printf("width: %d\theight: %d\tx: %d\ty: %d\n", child_attr.width, child_attr.height, child_attr.x, child_attr.y);
    std::printf("mouse_x: %d\tmouse_y: %d\n", win_x, win_y);

    int x_mouse_offset = win_x - child_attr.x;
    int y_mouse_offset = win_y - child_attr.y;
    std::printf("x_mouse_offset: %d\ty_mouse_offset: %d\n", x_mouse_offset, y_mouse_offset);
    XImage *image = XGetImage(display, child, x_mouse_offset, y_mouse_offset, 1, 1, AllPlanes, XYPixmap);
    if (!image) {
        perror("no image returned");
        return 1;
    }

    std::printf("image: %d %d (%p)\n", image->width, image->height, image->data);
    c.pixel = XGetPixel(image, 0, 0);
    XFree(image);
    Colormap cm = DefaultColormap(display, 0);
    XQueryColor(display, cm, &c);
    std::cout << c.red/255 << " " << c.green/255 << " " << c.blue/255 << "\n";
    XCloseDisplay(display);
   return 0;
}
```

I have searched for a way to evaluate rgba values in X11 but I didn't find anything.